# Dropdown based on previous dropdown using php class

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have the following dropdown in my page

```
<label for="state">State: </label>
<select name="state" class="dropdown">
<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
<?php echo $states->getStates(); ?>
</select>
```

The dropdown itself works and populates itself with states no problem. But now i want it to be able to choose a state and based on that state the city dropdown shows up with the corresponding cities of that state.

Below is the class that i have. I just can't figure out how to call the getCity function of myclass and pass it the selected value from the state dropdown.

## states.php

```
class states{
function getStates(){
        $success = false;
        try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(state) FROM tbl_zip ORDER BY state ASC";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->execute();


            $valid = $stmt->fetchAll();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
                    $list = "";
                    // Loop through list of states
                    foreach($valid as $row) {
                        $list .= '<option value=\"' . $row["state"] .'\">' . $row["state"] . '</option>';
                    }   

            }


            $con = null;
            return $list;
         }catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return $success;
         }
    }

    function getCity($state){
        $success = false;
        try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tbl_zip WHERE state = :state ORDER BY city ASC";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "state", $state , PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();


            $valid = $stmt->fetchAll();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
                    $list = '<select name=\"state\">';
                    $list .= '<option value=\"\" selected>Please Select</option>';
                    // Loop through list of states
                    foreach($valid as $row) {
                        $list .= '<option value=\"' . $row["city"] .'\">' . $row["city"] . '</option>';
                    }   
                    $list .= '</select>';
            }


            $con = null;
            return $list;
         }catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return $success;
         }
    }                                               
}
```

Comment: Usually,people implement this kind of function by using AJAX call, you make a get/post call to city.php page and get return array/json code and use javascript to update the value of city dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what exactly troubles you, but how about this:

```
$city = $states->getCity($_POST['state']);
```

Comment: That looks good, but i didn't realize i could post directly to a class

Comment: but how would i be able to do that when a user chooses a state?

Comment: That's easy. Just add a check for post data like this if (isset($_POST['state'])) {} and populate your select element accordingly. So when user submits your form, page reloads and post data sent. If state is selected and passed, then the 2nd select with cities list will be populated. It can be done without page reloading of course, but I guess you should learn the basics for now.